# Why does adding an arbitrary GET variable speeds up a long-time-taking request?

Tags: caching, networking, get, httprequest

Sometimes, I request a page and it takes *too* long to receive a response for the request and then load the page (sometimes the request times out and I never get a response).

However, if I open a new tab, copy the exact URL, and then append it with an arbitrary `GET` variable (with an arbitrary value), the request gets a response very fast (as the normal state is) and the page then loads, although the request wasn't getting a response without that arbitrary `GET` variable.

For a fake example, if I request:

http://example.com/

It might take a long time just loading, not receiving any response yet, but if I just open a new tab (at the same time), and request:

http://example.com/?foo=bar

It loads like magic!

Why is that happening to me? what could be the reason along the road between my browser and the page's server? does that have any relevance to ISP servers caching?

Any explanation is much, much appreciated, as I really am eager to know the reason!

**P.S:** I'm in Syria (where anything crazy is possible in Internet network), and this doesn't happen only to me, but to all people I know.

**EDIT:**

Note that it happens even if a URL has a `GET` variable already, for a real example I have a blog, and sometimes requesting this page (I changed the domain):

http://myblogdomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack

Takes too long time (and sometimes it times out), but if I open a new tab and request:

http://myblogdomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack&foo=bar

It loads fast (as normal).

Comment: What happens if you do it in the other order?

Comment: @SLaks: The other order of what? if you mean `bar=foo`, then that's just arbitrary as I said, anything just gets the job done!

Comment: try analysing the delay with yslow or pagespeed any other debugger see where is the delay origin.

Comment: are you using something like Tor ?

Comment: @M.H: No, in fact the problem doesn't happen when I use Tor (although response and loading become a bit slower, but that's the normal speed of browsing with tor).

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that there is a caching proxy and/or firewall between you and the rest of the internet.  There is probably a rule in the proxy that says URLs with GET parameters can pass through since they are likely to return unique content, but URL's without parameters must be fetched through a cache.  The cache is likely overloaded or broken.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a proxy that needs to do some lengthy process (content check, DNS lookup, etc) once per domain.

When you open the second tab, that length process would have already started (for the first tab), so it wouldn't take as long.

If this is the case, opening the first tab with a querystring and the second tab without would still result in the second tab loading faster.

Comment: I have already tried that, but it doesn't work. Only adding a new `GET` variable speeds up the request, requesting the exact same URL in another tab just causes it to wait as the first tab, and if a response is received then both receive a response at the same time usually.

Comment: What about a different URL on the same domain but without a querystring?

Comment: It acts independently, i.e, might get fast response or face the same problem, just independent.

Answer (score -1):

1-form a web developer perspective :
to get more details about what is taking this time , i could the network tab of my best friend (firebug )

[image]

as you may see above , i can see how much time spent on each step on the page .

2-even though i think this question should be moved to https://serverfault.com/ to get answers form  networks geeks